Why might PHP be incorrectly detecting it is running a web (and not a console) context?
I have a PHP script on a shared web host that reads a lot of log files and summarises data in JSON format. This script is run periodically via Cron. I do not control the server, but I have FTP access.
The cron entry for this script is thus:
0    1    *    *    *    php /home/username/public_html/example.com/minecraft-graph/src/process.php > /home/username/public_html/example.com/minecraft-graph/output-hourly.json

In other words, at 1am daily, the script is run and the JSON output is written to a JSON file. The JSON is loaded by a website front end and used to draw a graph.
Now, here's the odd thing. The JSON fetch in the web app recently broke, and I can see why. The JSON file, to which stdout is redirected, now looks like this:
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.3.33
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

{
    "averages": [
        {
            "year": 2023,
            "month": 1,
            "date": 15,
            "hour": 16,
            "average": 0
        },
        {

Obviously the headers here are going to make the JSON file invalid.
Since Apache is not involved here, PHP must be rendering those headers. Moreover, this script used to work fine, so I think the host owner has reconfigured something. (I should think they have some kind of CPanel system).
My initial thought to fix this is to do this in the code:
header_remove('X-Powered-By');
header_remove('Content-type');

However this is a bit yucky, and I wonder if there is a switch I can give to PHP to stop it rendering any headers. Something is making the judgement that it is running in a web context, and (being run from Cron on the console) it obviously isn't.
Updates
After trying new search terms, I've now found this question, and it recommends -q, but that appears to be deprecated since 5.2. I might try it though: on my local system it seems not to cause an error with a 7.x installation. (But also my local system does not render these headers, so it is hard to tell if this is the fix).
Also, one of the comments on this manual page suggests a hashbang might fix it. I might try that too, though I wonder if that would stop me running the script via the web for debugging.

Maybe it's a good idea to first do your research, before you ask the question? I have another idea: Instead of redirecting the output of your PHP script to the JSON file on the command line, you could let the PHP script write to that file directly. There are many methods to do this.

@KIKOSoftware: you'll just have to take my word for it that it was researched beforehand. On a whim I tried a different search, and found the possible Stack Overflow duplicate. (I say "possible" as it is a deprecated flag).

However, trying Cron command amendments is not trivial in my case, because I have to send an updated command to an account owner, who will install them and wait for a new 1am to come around. I cannot, unfortunately, do this myself.

Unfortunately I also cannot replicate a PHP binary that does this header output locally, because I do not know the cause of it.

Yes, writing to file within the script is possible. When I wrote this originally I thought that doing things the *nix way was cleanest, though I may have to change my mind. I will see how the -q flag fares first.

You could write the output to another JSON file, and keep the old file for debug purposes. That way you probably don't have to contact the account owner.

Yes, I do have write access to the PHP script and the JSON file, albeit via unencrypted FTP! I will update this thread with what I try.

I think your problem is that the wrong PHP is being used on the CLI. I just made an empty file using touch file.php. Then I ran /usr/bin/php-cgi7.4 file.php and I saw some HTTP headers being dumped out. When I switch to the correct CLI using /usr/bin/php-7.4 file.php (which is what my php is ultimately linked to) nothing is printed. You might want to do which php to see what it is linked to, or just see if you can be explicit about the binary.

@ChrisHaas: Yes, that would be ideal, but halfer doesn't have access to the command line, only FTP.

That's a very good train of thought @ChrisHaas. I wonder if I could do some research using PHP to run some commands (which php and the like).

The php command being linked to the CGI version and not the console version would not be a surprising misconfiguration for this kind of host, IMO.

I've just run a test using passthru and can confirm I have /usr/bin/php with no CGI variants, and also I have /bin/php with no CGI variants. php is matched to /bin/php first. I assume these are all CGI builds and there is no console-friendly binary available.

Try echoing out the PHP_SAPI constant: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-sapi

Great suggestion @Chris. The value is cgi-fcgi, which feels very "web-ish". I wonder if there is no cli build on this box.

I got a server account holder to update the Cron job with -q, and this has indeed fixed it. So, even though the flag is deprecated, I will go with that as the solution. I wonder if there is no appetite to remove it, even though it is no longer in the php -h help.

(I am inclined to close this Q as a duplicate of the linked one, notwithstanding the flag deprecation. It is perhaps not a bad thing that I've made another signpost. But I will give it a day or two to see if anyone wishes to add an answer.)
